# How can I create an FTP drop box that another user can see?

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp

*Disclaimer, I won't lie, am restarting a question I couldn't solve before*

On Linux I want to create a dropbox where an FTP user can write files (user A), but not see them afterwards, while another user (user B) can read and manipulate those files. I have tried groups, I have tried changing the umask for user A as far as 777, but in the end when User A writes a file to the server, only user A has rights to it. Yes, user B has rights to the directory, but not the files that user A drops into the directory.

User B runs a Perl script that processes the data in the files, and so far it only works if I run the Perl script as **su**, but we know that's dangerous.

I have no idea what it is that I am doing wrong, but am sure it's a simple thing. Is it the ftp users config? The directory permissions? This is driving me nuts,

Thanks,

Comment: Aside from the main issue, FTP is [outdated and insecure](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie).

Comment: It may be, but I'm still going to run into my main issue of permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

umasks (in a profile file) rarely work outside of a shell session (in FTP or sFTP) unless the program you're using has it's own umask implementation.

If you're using a filesystem that supports ACLs (and is mounted with ACLs enabled), you could set a default permission on the drop box directory so that userB always has access to new files.

`setfacl -m -d user:userB:rwx /path/to/dropbox`

`-m` is to modify existing ACLs (still works if starting from a fresh slate)

`-d` is to set a default (only applicable on directories) so that all new files inherit a set of permissions.

`user:userB:rwx` the first "user" is specifying you're setting permissions for a user (as opposed to a group), userB is the name of the user to give access to, and rwx is the permissions you're granting (read/write/execute).

Comment: FOr anyone else reading this the above answer is correct with regards to umask/  Just remember that there's a separate umask setting for FTP users.

Answer (score 0):

Closing this question because I realized that there is a umask for FTP users as well as a different set of umask for users on the server.  Once I changed the FTP user's umask to give others the right to read files that the FTP user drops into the drop box.